# What php.ini file uses symfony server:run command?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using virtphp to have separate environments (different PHP versions, extensions, etc).

When I use symfony's command to run a local development server:

```
php app/console server:run
```

It seems that it ignores the php.ini file of my virtual environment (~/.virtenv/envs/myenv/etc/php.ini), e.g.: does not load the extensions definided in that file.

But when I use the php built-in server **directly**, it works perfectly:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 --docroot=web/
```

What's the difference of those two commands or what does symfony do differently?

This is the output of the `php --ini` command:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /Users/mjuarez/.virtphp/envs/wowfi/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /Users/mjuarez/.virtphp/envs/wowfi/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

This is the output of the function `phpinfo()` in a Symfony controller when using the command `php app/console server:run`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /Users/mjuarez/.virtphp/envs/wowfi/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
```

Note the difference in "Loaded Configuration File"... when I use the `php --ini` command it replaces the "Loaded Configuration file" with the one in my php virtual environment and when I use the command `php app/console server:run` it uses the "global" configuration file.

Comment: `php -i` will tell you what .ini file(s) were loaded

Comment: Thanks @MarcB indeed the command that shows you the .ini files that php will load is  `php --ini` ... but the output of that commands shows that it's loading the both files the "global" php.ini and the php.ini in my virtual envionment.

Comment: some(but not all) .ini directives can be overriden at run-time with `ini_set()` calls. `php -S` isn't running symphony directly, it'll just be waiting for an http request and THEN runs symphony.

Comment: @MarcB do you thinks Symfony is overwriting some of the settings of my virtual environment php.ini file?

Comment: .ini is parsed once at php startup. ini_set() can be executed ANYTIME during the lifetime of a script.

Comment: It is not a symfony thing, all of the loading is done by php itself.  Use php -c to ignore your global file.

Comment: I tried `php -c app/console server:run` and I get the following error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is to move the php.ini file of my **virtual environment** to a sub-directory called php inside the etc directory. e.g.:

Move the file `~/.virtphp/envs/my-env/etc/php.ini`

To `~/.virtphp/envs/my-env/etc/php/php.ini`

Answer (score 3):

For the record (and for all lost souls who arrive here by Google search like me):

Symfony console is not a program per se. It is just a PHP script. Therefore, when you run Symfony console, it doesn't have its own php.ini or extension directory or other configuration - **It uses the same settings as all your other PHP scripts.** (Unless overwritten at runtime - which actually might be the case of the original question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another piece for the "lost souls" who arrive here - Symfony does overwrite at least the `max_execution_time`, when Symfony commands are called through the console.  Check the console.php file, there's a "set_time_limit(0)" in line #12 or so.

Answer (score -1):

Drop a file in your web directory with  inside. Open it with your browser and search for php.ini that will give you the correct file. There could be several files yf you look directy in your configuration directory (cli, fpm, apache and so on)